# createComponent Salesforce lightning error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am creating lightning component dynamically. On callback, I am facing a strange error which should not come.

```
 $A.createComponent(
            "c:TestComponent",
            {
                parameter1 : "hey"
            },
            function(newComponent, status){
                    var con = component.find('container');
                    if (component.isValid() && con.isValid() && status === 'SUCCESS') {
                        var body = con.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newComponent);
                        con.set("v.body", body);
                    }                
            });
```

and .cmp file I have

```
<div aura:id="container" class="slds-align-top"> 
</div>
```

and I am getting error in if condition.

```
con.isValid is not a function
```

Since container itself is not valid, I am not able to read the body of container where I want to include newly created component? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, component.find() is returning something other than exactly one value. Creating a Minimum Viable Reproduction, I wrote this code:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <div aura:id="container" class="slds-align-top"> 
    </div>

</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:test",
            null,
            function(newComponent, status){
                var con = component.find('container');
                if (component.isValid() && con.isValid() && status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    var body = con.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newComponent);
                    con.set("v.body", body);
                }                
            });     
    }
})
```

---

And the component was created correctly and appeared on the page. Make sure you have exactly one element named "container".